# How to register IFilter<PublishContext<T>> in MassTransit when using Autofac extensions

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am using Autofac extensions and can't find how to register `IFilter<PublishContext<T>>` which has dependencies. The docs suggest to use `UsePublishFilter(typeof(TFilter<>), context)` but where to get the `context`?

```
public static ContainerBuilder RegisterMassTransit(this ContainerBuilder builder, Func<IBusRegistrationContext, IBusControl> createBusFunc, Assembly consumerAssembly = null)
{
    builder.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
    {
        if (consumerAssembly != null)
        {
            cfg.AddConsumers(consumerAssembly);
        }

        cfg.AddBus(createBusFunc);
    });

    return builder;
}

public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .RegisterMassTransit(CreateBus, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .RegisterTelemetryCollector();
}

private IBusControl CreateBus(IBusRegistrationContext registrationContext)
{
    return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(_serviceBusConnectionString);

            cfg.UsePublishFilter(typeof(MyFilterWithDependencies<>), ????);
        });
}
```

There is seemingly an overload but where to get the `ILifetimeScopeProvider`?

```
public static void UsePublishFilter(this IPublishPipelineConfigurator configurator, Type filterType, ILifetimeScopeProvider lifetimeScopeProvider)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `registrationContext` as the second argument.

Comment: That's correct, I just now realized that my issue was the ambiguity because the exact same overload is available from two static extension classes, so I had to call the Autofac one directly `AutofacFilterExtensions.UsePublishFilter(cfg, typeof(ChaosEngineFilter<>), registrationContext);`